# Array key want to start from custom number not zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is part of my code and I want key to start from number 5 instead of zero (default(:

```
  var array = [];

  for(var i = 5; i < 10; ++i) {
     array.push(i);
  }

  console.log(array);
```

and the result is:

```
0:5
1:6
2:7
3:8
4:9
5:10
```

the desired result is:

```
   5:5
   6:6
   7:7
   8:8
   9:9
   10:10
```

Comment: @Fi3n1k I have edit your code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Array's index are 0-based** and this can't be changed *programmatically*, but you can set values from 6th index instead of first.

Instead of `array.push`, set the value at `index`

```
array[i] = i;
```

However, if the expectation is that the length of array should stay 5 instead of 10, **then it is impossible**.

Comment: length shows as 10.

Comment: @Afsar OP didn't mentioned any criteria of length only the desired result.

Comment: what if we have criteria for length ?

Comment: Then it is impossible

Comment: Yes, but please mention that in your answer for clarity. That is at least not obvious (i.e. not more obvious than the solution itself...).

Comment: @Frax Sure, edited the answer. I thought I answered it in first sentence itself, anyways added a note for more clarity.

Comment: The problem with `array[i] = i;` is that the result is ok but it creates empty `[empty × 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` without adding those empty it would be ok @gurvinder372

Comment: @Fi3n1k No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. The solution can be to create an object using numeric properties starting at 5 but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for you to do that! 
Instead you could go for objects

Ex :

```
var obj = {
             5: 5,
             6: 6,
             7: 7,
             ...
          }
```

Or you could store null values in the indexes where you don't have valid values and store boolean/other values in the indexes where you need. This is a lesser efficient solution compared to the above one.
Ex :

```
var arr = [null,null,null,null,null, 5, 6, 7, 8 . . . . .  ];
```

or

```
var arr = [false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true . . . ]
```